# User unregistration

Tags: users

I'm looking for the most Drupal way to allow registered users to request unregistration.

The website would provide a form to request the unregistration from the site, and the administration would then confirm the unregistration.

Is there a module that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "Cancel own user account" permission in `admin/people/permissions`. If you assign it to your authenticated users, they will see a "Cancel account" link in their user profile ("Edit" tab). Would it be enough for your needs?

Additionally, you can configure the way the account is cancelled, in `admin/config/people/accounts`, in the "When cancelling a user account" section.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Using the configuration mentioned above, you could "disable" the account instead of deleting it. You could also set up a rule so that admins are emailed when a user cancels/disables their account.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to create a form that sends an email to admin users with a link to cancel the account. In the email that is sent, you would just have to use the token for the Current User ID and create a link to cancel the account (yourwebsite.com/user/xxx/cancel) where xxx = their User ID.

The admin would just have to click the link in the email and follow through with the steps to cancel/deactivate the account.